# Storage Shows Two SD Cards?

Tags: sd-card

Nokia 1
Android 9
Storage shows one SD card in use and a second SD card not inserted.
There is only one SD card in the phone...
Please see image.[image: Storage Settings]

Comment: Maybe a glitch with the file manager (built in?) you are using. Try with a different file manager. Plenty of them on Play Store.

Comment: I have the same symptom right after formatting a card to be used as extended storage and moving data to it. A lot of files are missing and some apps are crashing.